# Can't connect two 3D objects in CAD

Tags: autocad

I'm trying to 3D print tubing that is shaped a bit like a "serpentine" pattern. I'm able to draw the 3D cylinder and the 3D elbow shape end, but they aren't connected for some reason. [Here is a picture showing the gap between the objects.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiqbB.jpg)

I know there's a way to connect a gap like this with 2D objects but I can't figure out how to connect these two 3D objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ending surfaces of "elbow shape" are not tangential to cylinder, because they are parpendicular to generatrix arc. This arc should be 180 deg. You should change the base arc, or use eliptical arc.

Comment: I ended up redrawing it just as a line and then sweeping. Thanks!